# two-sample KS test: data becomes significantly different after normalization

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, normalization

I'm currently working on a data set with two sets of samples. The csv file of the data could be found [here](http://pastebin.com/200v10py). I would like to use KS test to see if these two sets of samples are from different distributions.

I ran the following R script:

```
# read data from the file
> data = read.csv('data.csv')
> ks.test(data[[1]], data[[2]])
    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  data[[1]] and data[[2]]
D = 0.025, p-value = 0.9132
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The KS test shows that these two samples are very similar. (In fact, they should come from same distribution.)

However, due to some reasons, instead of the raw values, the actual data that I will get will be normalized (zero mean, unit variance). So I tried to normalize the raw data I have and run the KS test again:

```
> ks.test(scale(data[[1]]), scale(data[[2]]))
    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  scale(data[[1]]) and scale(data[[2]])
D = 0.3273, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The p-value becomes almost zero after normalization indicating these two samples are significantly different (from different distributions).

My question is: **How the normalization could make two similar samples becomes different from each other?** I can see that if two samples are different, then normalization could make them similar. However, if two sets of data are similar, then intuitively, applying same operation onto them should make them still similar, at least not different from each other too much.

I did some further analysis about the data. I also tried to normalize the data into [0,1] range (using the formula `(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))`), but same thing happened. At first, I thought it might be outliers caused this problem (I can see that an outlier may cause this problem if I normalize the data into [0,1] range.) I deleted all data whose abs value is larger than 4 standard deviation. But it still didn't help. Plus, I even plotted the eCDFs, they look the same even after normalization. Anything wrong with my usage of the R function?

Since the data contains ties, I also tried [ks.boot](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/matching/ks.boot.html), but I got the same result.

Could anyone help me to explain why it happened? Also, any suggestion about the hypothesis testing on normalized data? (The data I have right now is simulated data. In real world, I cannot get raw data, but only normalized one.)

Comment: Are the data paired?

Comment: Indeed, note that the correlation between values is quite strong. What is it you're actually interested in finding out?

Comment: @Glen_b No, they are not paired. I would like to see if these two samples are from same distribution. I think ks test could serve this purpose (partially?) To my understanding, ks test could identify significant difference between two samples.

Comment: I don't find this denial plausible, absent some other explanation. Note that large values ($>2\times 10^7$) *only* occur together. If the data are independent, how is this possible? There are 951 pairs of values (out of of 1000) that are both ($<2\times 10^7$) and 49 pairs of values that are both ($>2\times 10^7$), and no data whatever where one value is above that threshold and one is below. If these data were independent this would be astronomically unlikely. How do you account for clear dependence if they're not dependent?

Comment: Well. In fact, I lied in the topic about the data source. They are not simulated, they are actual data. I said simulated simply to save some words. The data is in fact the response times of a database. I issued 1000 transactions to collect the first dataset and issued another 1000 transactions to collect the other dataset. The transactions are all write only, making there is little inference between the cache. I think the fact you observed is only by chance.

Comment: Are the first transactions, second transactions, etc the same each time? [I don't think the effect I observed can plausibly be explained by chance. Your values have a correlation > 0.9. The chance of observing a correlation of that size with those margins if the data were independent is (again) astronomically small. Independence is not a plausible claim and so the KS test cannot apply. {There are numerous other issues in your post to deal with, but until we find out why your data are *actually* paired, the rest must wait.} ]

Comment: @Glen_b Yes. All transactions are same. (A simple UPDATE statement which updates a single row in a table.) Do you think it caused the problem I mentioned? What I'm concerning is that the normalization process makes two sets of samples *less* similar, which is counter-intuitive to me. I thought normalization would make two data set much more similar to each other. Do you think it might be the size of the data? I know that KS test may always reject the null hypothesis when the data size is large.

Comment: What I am trying to find out is what is it that is making the $i$-th transaction in the first column more like the $i$-th transaction in the second column than it is like the $j$-th transaction in the first column (on average). Until we have that absolutely clear, worrying about the remaining issues is pointless. Your data are dependent; once it's clear how and why, suitable advice should become clearer. So when you say "all transactions are (the) same", that doesn't make values in the same row more alike. It would require both transactions for row-i to be more alike than for rows-i and -j

Comment: I see. Currently, a possible explanation to me is that it may related to the buffer flushing mechanism with the database. My theory is: Assuming database (or OS) will flush its buffer once there're more than N dirty rows. My strategy is: issue an UPDATE request every second for 1000 times; then restart the VM and issue another 1000 requests. That's might be the reason you saw the pairs since every N requests, there'll be a flush (The VM is a clean VM and there's no other workload to it.)

Comment: That would suggest a trend in the values within each column, would it not? There's no hint of it in the data. Actually, strike that, I spoke too soon -- there is a suggestion of a trend (the early values are a bit lower, later values higher). But I am quite sure it's not enough on its own to explain the problem; the effect is relatively mild compared to the dependence.

Comment: By "problem", do you mean the problem of paired data, or the problem of "normalization makes samples less similar"? Some update on my side: I tried to down-sample the data from 1000 data points to 100 data points. It seems the p-value is increased. Not sure if that helps. Thank you for your comments, BTW.

Comment: We're still on the pairing. As I have explained, there's no point in discussing the problems like the issue with scaling until the issues with pairing is worked out, since the dependence renders KS-tests moot anyway. With the trend, even if you split the data into subgroups you still have the same problem. For every sufficiently big A, there's a similarly big B; accounting for the trend doesn't change that.

Comment: I wonder if it is correct to apply KS test to standardized residuals? This involved estimation of location and scale parameters. It's not immediately obvious to me that you can do this in two-sample test.

Answer (score 2):

I hope to replace this with a full answer once we have sorted out what's going on.

In trying to show you what's going on with the dependence in large vs small values, I see another problem:

[image]

The y-values have been monotonically transformed (log(y-2.e6)) for clarity.

The green box shows how the large values always occur together.

But they're also astonishingly *regular*. It looks like the large ones are every 20th value.

The red ovals show another problem. Notice patches of almost pure-black followed by almost pure-blue in the red ovals? There's something weird going on. Why would the middling-size values alternate, with a patch from column 1 then a patch from column 2?

You have neither independence within columns nor within pairs, but I am not sure what is causing that particular alternation in the red ovals.

Comment: I just ran several other rounds of testing and collected another 8 sets of data (1000 points each). About the green box: Yes, in every set of samples, I could observe that the value will increase every ~20 samples. I think I'm pretty sure it is caused by the flushing mechanism in the database. (recap: The values are response times of a database write-query.) About the red ovals, I'm currently do not have a good explanation. However, does the column-independence really matter? I mean, what if I do a permutation for the data, which does not change the eCDF of the sample.

Comment: It's not just within-column-dependence there. There's a negative dependence in the medium-sized values (roughly in the range of $y$ where the red ovals are) -- when the the black ones tend to get that high for a period, the blue ones don't, and vice versa. It's a very complex situation, not merely positive dependence overall, but negative dependence in that region of values. Very odd.